# Filling an array with random numbers in a for-loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random

I am trying to write a program in Java that asks the user how many random numbers to generate (0-999) Then the program is supposed to fill an array up with the random numbers and present them to the user.

This is what I got so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class random2
{
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    Random random;
    int i;
    int[] numbers;
    int numberOfNumbers=0;
    int upperRange=999;
    int lowerRange=0;
    int randomNumber=0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many random numbers between 0-999?");
    numberOfNumbers=in.nextInt();
    numbers = new int [numberOfNumbers];


    random = new Random();

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfNumbers; i++){

    randomNumber = random.nextInt(upperRange-lowerRange) + lowerRange;
    numbers[i] = randomNumber;

    if (i==numberOfNumbers) 

    System.out.println(randomNumber);


    }      


  }

}
```

But the program won't present the list of the random numbers. It just exits. What did I do wrong?

Comment: In your loop, `i` will never equal `numberOfNumbers` (your loop condition is `i < numberOfNumbers`). Print the array after the loop.

Comment: Am voting to open the re-question since the reason of not working is related to the logic in this condition *if (i==numberOfNumbers) * and nothing to do with how arrays must be printed.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch but when I try to print the array after the loop, it only presents 1 random number. I will check out the link on arrays.

Comment: Print `numbers` (the array), not `randomNumber` (**one** random number).

Comment: Your loop exits before `i==numberOfNumbers` becomes true. Some people use code indentation for a reason.

Comment: I tried that @ElliottFrisch but then the program prints "These are the random numbers: I@1b84c92"